# Proper usage of Streams in Java

Tags: java, optimization, java-8, java-stream

I've a use-case where I need to parse key-value pairs (separated by `=`) and put these key-value pairs in a `LinkedHashMap`.

I want to ignore the following type of `String`s

- key is empty or contains only spaces
- value is empty or contains only spaces
- those `String`s which don't contain a `=`.

Now, I have solved it using imperative style and by using streams also.

The following are the 2 variants:

### Solution by iterative style - `for` loop and lots of `if`

```java
public static Map<String, String> getMap1(String[] array) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String currentString = array[i];
        int index = currentString.indexOf('=');

        // ignoring strings that don't contain '='
        if (index == -1) continue;
        String key = currentString.substring(0, index).trim();
        String value = currentString.substring(index + 1).trim();

        // ignoring strings with empty key or value
        if (key.length() == 0 || value.length() == 0) continue;

        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

#### Solution that uses `Stream`s - pretty clean code

```java
public static Map<String, String> getMap(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .filter(s -> s.indexOf('=') != -1) // ignore strings that don't contain '='
            .filter(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf('=')).trim().length() != 0) // key should be present
            .filter(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().length() != 0) // value should be present
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf('=')).trim(),
                    s -> s.substring(s.indexOf('=') + 1).trim(),
                    (first, second) -> second,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));

}
```

I'm worried here because while using `Stream`s, I'm calling the `indexOf` method multiple times. (And for big strings, I can end-up recalculating the same thing again and again).

**Is there a way I can avoid re-computation done by `indexOf` method** in such a way that the code is still clean. (I know talking about clean-code is very subjective, but I want don't want to open multiple streams, of loop through the original string-array and subsequently pre-computing the indices of `=` and re-using that).

Clubbing multiple `filter`s into a single filter again seem to be an option but that would make my predicate pretty ugly.

(This is a result of my idle musing where I wish to learn/improve).

Comment: why didn't use `split` instead `indexOf`? also this code will be break for two `=` in `array[i]` as you said: _those Strings which don't contain a `=`_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
 String[]  array = {"aaa2=asdas","aaa=asdasd"};

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> aaa = Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
            .filter(s -> s.length == 2) // ignore strings that don't contain '='
            .peek(s -> { s[0] = s[0].trim(); })
            .peek(s -> { s[1] = s[1].trim(); })
            .filter(s -> s[0].length() != 0) // key should be present
            .filter(s -> s[1].length() != 0) // value should be present
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    s -> s[0],
                    s -> s[1],
                    (first, second) -> second,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: what will happen for `"aaa2=asdas=asd"`?

Comment: Ah, split was the thing I was missing. Thanks Nonika and Hadi J :)
@HadiJ, yes it won't work for `aaa2=asdas=asd` but I'm happy that split does this in a good way. Thanks

Comment: @LavishKothari you can add a second parameter `limit` to the `split`-Method

Comment: There is no need to abuse `peek` here, as a clean `.map(s -> new String[] { s[0].trim(), s[1].trim() })` would do. But using `.map(s -> s.trim().split("\\s*=\\s*", 2))` as the first operation would completely eliminate the need to `trim()` afterwards. And to me, a single `.filter(s -> s[0].length() != 0 && s[1].length() != 0)` is simpler than two `filter` steps.

Comment: @Holger doing it that way you have to create a new String Array, which comes with some overhead.

Comment: @codeflush.dev that’s negligible compared to the overhead of the other operations. Further, my comment shows an alternative avoiding that additional operation completely. If you care about overhead of that magnitude, there are alternatives that can elide the other array creation (of `split`) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use split instead of indexOf and StringUtils to check that your keys and values are not empty.

```
 public static Map<String, String> getMap(String[] array) {
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                .filter(s -> s.contains("="))
                .map(s -> s.split("="))
                .filter(s -> s.length == 2 && isNotBlank(s[0]) && isNotBlank(s[1]))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        s -> s[0].trim(),
                        s -> s[1].trim()));
    }
```